# Find the mean of two values

Tags: c++

A very easily stated problem that has a surprising number of gotchas - return a value that's midway between the two supplied values.

Depending on the types given, we need to be aware of

- arithmetic overflow and underflow
- infinities
- NaNs
- rounding

For pointers and iterators, the mean only makes sense if the values point into the same object; the results are otherwise undefined.  For forward-only iterators, the arguments need to be in the correct order; for other types, either order is accepted.

For aggregate types, we just need to compute the mean element-wise.  I've provided code for arrays and complex numbers; third-party aggregates (e.g. "point" and "vector" geometric types) can be implemented by following the existing pattern.

I expect the template to work unaltered for other arithmetic classes (e.g. bignum and rational types).

```
#include <cmath>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace std {
    template<typename T> class complex;
    template<typename T, std::size_t N> class array;
}

namespace _
{
    template<typename T>
    concept arithmetic = std::regular<T> && requires(T a, T b) {
        a + (b - a); a < b;
    };

    template<arithmetic T>
    T midpoint(T a, T b)
    {
        if (a == b) {
            // this ensures infinities are correctly returned
            return a;
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
            if (std::isnan(a)) { return a; }
            if (std::isnan(b)) { return b; }
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) {
            if ((a < 0) != (b < 0)) {
                return (a + b) / 2;
            }
        }

        if (a > b) {
            using std::swap;
            swap(a, b);
        }

        return a + (b - a) / 2;
    }

    // Non-random-access iterators
    // a MUST be before b
    template<std::forward_iterator T>
    requires (!std::bidirectional_iterator<T>)
    T midpoint(T a, T b)
    {
        bool skip = false;
        T mid = a;
        while (a != b) {
            ++a;
            if (!skip) { ++mid; }
            skip = !skip;
        }
        return mid;
    }

    // Aggregate types follow
    // Pattern can be extended, e.g. for popular geometry types

    template<arithmetic T>
    std::complex<T> midpoint(std::complex<T> a, std::complex<T> b)
    {
        return {
            midpoint(a.real(), b.real()),
            midpoint(a.imag(), b.imag())
        };
    }

    template<arithmetic T, std::size_t N>
    std::array<T,N> midpoint(const std::array<T,N>& a, const std::array<T,N>& b)
    {
        std::array<T,N> result;
        for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < N;  ++i) {
            result[i] = midpoint(a[i], b[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

using _::midpoint;
```

### // Tests

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <climits>
TEST(midpoint, int)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 0), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 1), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 2), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1, 3), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(4, 1), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MIN, 0), INT_MIN/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, 0), INT_MAX/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, -INT_MAX), 0);
}

#include <limits>
TEST(midpoint, double)
{
    static constexpr auto inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0.0, 0.0), 0.0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, 2.0), 1.5);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(inf, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(-inf, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(inf, -inf)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, 0.0)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(0.0, nan)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, nan)));
}

#include <complex>
TEST(midpoint, complex)
{
    auto const a = std::complex{2,10};
    auto const b = std::complex{0,20};
    auto const c = std::complex{1,15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}

TEST(midpoint, pointer)
{
    auto const s = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+1, s+25), s+13);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+25, s+1), s+13);
}

#include <string_view>
TEST(midpoint, iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.begin(), s.end()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.end(), s.begin()), 'n');
}

#include <forward_list>
TEST(midpoint, forward_iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    auto const l = std::forward_list(s.begin(), s.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l.begin(), l.end()), 'n');
}

#include <array>
TEST(midpoint, std_array)
{
    auto const a = std::array{ 0, 10, 20};
    auto const b = std::array{10, 10, 10};
    auto const c = std::array{5, 10, 15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}
```

I've intentionally included some questionable choices:

- `_` as a namespace name is legal, but is it a good choice for the implementation-private namespace?
- I believe I can forward-declare the template classes that belong to `std`, rather than drag in their entire headers.
- The `arithmetic` concept has very similar name to `std::is_arithmetic` - could/should I change that?
- The unit-tests still pass if I remove the early exit for NaN inputs, but should I retain them anyway?  (The checks were once needed, but refactoring them has left them redundant).
- In the first test case, I assume that `-INT_MAX` is valid - could that legally overflow?

I didn't yet enclose the code in a namespace - I would do that when I add include guards and make it a header.

Comment: [std::midpoint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) was added in C++20, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @Ayxan - I'm still waiting for Debian's cppreference package to get updated, and I missed that addition to C++20.  Turns out I was [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] but didn't know it!  The support for complex numbers and iterators is more than `std::midpoint` provides.

Comment: What is the point of `if ((a < 0) != (b < 0))`? Shouldn't the final `a + (b - a) / 2` work for all cases?

Comment: Maybe I should test `std::is_signed<T>` instead for that block?

Comment: Good idea. That would also obviate the need for `is_arithmetic_v` (and the slight ambiguity).

Comment: re _The arithmetic concept has very similar name to std::is_arithmetic - could/should I change that?_  **Can** you you `std::arithmetic` in place of `std::is_arithmetic_v` without changing anything else?

Comment: how does `requires { a + (b - a); }` do anything other than seeing if `+` and `-` are defined for type `T`?  We already know that `a` and `b` are the same type...  Maybe worrying that `-` actually returns a different type?  But pointers/iterators are not arithmetic types, so that name is confusing.  In general, it can use comments.

Comment: Having a difference that's a distinct type from a position is normally part of an [_affine space_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Informal_description).  Browsing that, I see the definition doesn't include scalar multiplication (which I thought was part of it) so that might be a good name.  `T` is an `affine_point`.

Comment: Why don’t you want it to work for bidirectional iterators?

Comment: I mean, you require forward iterators, but ban (via `requires (!std::bidirectional_iterator<T>)`) bidi iterators so, for example, `std::list::iterator` won’t work with any overload. Why ban bidi iterators?

Comment: @indi, it does seem that I need some additional tests for iterators that aren't pointers - I should have written `std::random_access_iterator` there.  Thanks!

Comment: @indi, mention that in an answer and you can have some points.  :)

Comment: Heh. You got it. 

Comment: `using std::swap;` looks out of place, especially if your only using `swap` once.

Comment: @jdt, it might look out of place, but that's the standard way to fall back to `std::swap` if no more specific `swap()` function is found during argument-dependent lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Missing check for `>` in `concept arithmetic`

Your `concept arithmetic` checks for `<`, in your code you are using both `<` and `>` to compare values of type `T`. Either check that both operators are supported, or use `if (!(a < b))` to check if you need to swap values.

## Consider not adding an overload for `std::array`

You added an overload for computing the midpoint of a `std::array`, however that raises some questions. For example, if you do this, why are you not also supporting `std::vector` and other types as well? And is element-wise midpoint always the desired operation?

Instead of adding yet more overloads, I would just avoid these questions by omitting this overload, and let the caller do it themselves. They can do this easily using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) or similar algorithms, for example:

```
std::vector<float> a{1, 2.718, 3.1415};
std::vector<float> b{9, 42, 1729};
std::vector<float> c;
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c), midpoint);
```

## Pass parameters by `const` reference

I would pass parameters by `const` reference whenever possible in templates. An optimizing compiler will make this as fast as passing by value for small types, but for more complex types, especially thoses with non-trivial constructors, it might be forced to make expensive copies if you pass by value.

## Be aware of C++20 iterator sentinels

C++20 allows ranges to have an [`end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/end) iterator that has a different type than the [`begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/begin) iterator. You might want to support that for your overload that works on iterators. You can use the [`std::sentinel_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for) concept to restrict the type of `b`.

Comment: The `std::array` overload was to some extent a sample, but also a basis for geometric vector types which might use `std::array` as storage.  Overloading for `std::vector` is generally less useful - and we're not able to compile-time ensure that they have equal lengths as we can for arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on sentinels.  I think I'll want to use `std::ranges::distance(a, b)` to handle that transparently.  I'll re-think the split between "main" and "iterator" overloads now.

Answer (score 3):

- `_` as a namespace name is legal, but is it a good choice for the implementation-private namespace?

This causes undefined behavior. Identifiers that start with an underscore are reserved in the global scope.

- I believe I can forward-declare the template classes that belong to `std`, rather than drag in their entire headers

Adding forward declarations to `std` is undefined behavior. Just include the appropriate headers instead.

---

```
if (std::isnan(a)) { return a; }
if (std::isnan(b)) { return b; }
```

This could be simplified to:

```
if (std::isnan(a) || std::isnan(b)) { return NAN; }
```

Comment: "[_Identifiers that start with an underscore are reserved in the global scope_](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.2)".  I'd always believed that only identifiers that start with underscore followed by a letter or another underscore are reserved - thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: Would it be better to just dispense with the `isnan()` check, since it's an unlikely path, and the arithmetic gives the correct result anyway?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I would remove the `isnan` check since the rest of the function doesn't rely on that. I did check with GCC and clang. None seems to elide that check either.

Comment: It looks like I can use `_` as a namespace identifier within my own namespace.

Comment: A _nested_ detail namespace is not in the global scope.  Putting _any_ simple name at global scope is asking for a clash as libraries and other code is combined.  It's odd that his "private details" namespace is not nested but stand-alone -- that would be better off using his name.